# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Discriminator' AspNetUsers Table

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

After a code first migration, adding a user using the register fails with:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Discriminator', table 'aspnet-BSF2013-20130918101120.dbo.AspNetUsers'; column does not allow nulls.

The create user code is the default code generated by the Project Template (Vs2013, MVC project with EF5)

Before a successful migration, the Registration code worked, so I'm guessing that membership has been altered by EF.

Comment: What did you do in the migration? Can we see the "Up" code

Comment: The migration was a single text column added to a table not connected to membership. I don't have the up code to hand at the moment.