# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Discriminator', table '...AspNetUsers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Entity Framework 6, MVC5, ASP Identity 2.0.

I'm new to Entity framework and ASP Identity.
I've created database with Code First approach, following these instructions: http://dotnetcodr.com/2014/07/10/introduction-to-entityframework-6-part-1-the-basics-of-code-first/
and applying them accordingly to my own project.

Tables were created, all fine. But when I'm trying to Register a new user, exception is thrown: "Entity Framework 6, ASP Identity. Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Discriminator', table '...AspNetUsers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."
Triggered by CreateAsync method within AccountController

Line 153:            {
Line 154:                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
Line 155:                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
Line 156:                if (result.Succeeded)
Line 157:                {

I'm not even sure which part of code I should paste here.

Here is my DbContext:

```
    public class BulkMailerContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public BulkMailerContext()
        : base("BulkMailerContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Email> Emails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubscriptionList> SubscriptionLists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Recipient> Recipients { get; set; }
}
```

And here is default Identity context:

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("BulkMailerContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

I haven't found much information about this exception.

This post
http://forums.asp.net/t/1974183.aspx?Cannot+insert+the+value+NULL+into+column+Discriminator
suggests that project has a class, inheriting from User. I don't have anything like that.

This post
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800655/calling-new-user-with-4-5-1-does-not-pass-column-discriminator-required-in-aspnetusers-tables
is about Web API project and Microsoft team said it's a bug, and they will fix it, as far as I got it

This one
[Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Discriminator' AspNetUsers Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938514/cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column-discriminator-aspnetusers-table-ef5-v)
doesn't offer any solution

This one
[Web API 2 cannot register user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056132/web-api-2-cannot-register-user)
suggests that in Identity 2.0 this has been fixed, but I have Identity 2.0 currently

I have automatic migrations - turned off, if it matters. But I've updated db manually from PM console with update-database command.

Any suggestions at all are welcome.

Comment: your Recipient entity is inheriting from ApplicationUser?

Comment: Nope, they are different. I'm building a mass mailer. ApplicationUser - is the logged in user. Recipient - is just a table with email addresses and names - for mass mailing.

Comment: did you add any property in ApplicationUser? if so, can you paste that code too?

Comment: No, I didn't touch ApplicationUser

Comment: Discriminator is a property of ApplicationUser in Identity 1.0, can you check your table in database if that column is there?

Comment: Yes, Discriminator column is in AspNetUsers table, not null.
I'm quire sure I have Identity 2.0. And I didn't even update from 1 to 2, I installed VS Update 4 with latest version and then created project from scratch.
Does this mean, I can try to remove this column from AspNetUsers table?

Comment: "add-migration InitialCreate -force". Hopefully in public override void Up() method you will see a line DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Discriminator"); Then build solution and "update-database"

Comment: I get:"Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201412131647478_FirstInitialisation].  
Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration."
So, I do "add-migration -ConfigurationTypeName Bulk_email_7.DAL.ApplicationContextMigrations.Configuration “FirstInitialisation” -force  
Re-scaffolding migration 'FirstInitialisation'."  
But that doesn't help. I still get this pending explicit migration warning.

Comment: did you try to delete all these  "DbMigrations", then build and then again add-migrations..

Comment: I deleted migrations, then ran enable-migrations, then add migration InitialCreate -force. No effect, discriminator column is still in the table...

Comment: @tmg, it actually worked after I deleted Identity tables in database. Before that, when I was trying to update-database, it complained that AspNetUsers table (or some other table) already exists in the database. Not quite sure what I've done, but it worked. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran "add-migration -ConfigurationTypeName ...ApplicationContextMigrations.Configuration "InitialCreate” -force"

Then, deleted all Identity tables from database.

Then ran "update-database ...ApplicationContextMigrations.Configuration"

And Discriminator column disappeared. User is registered successfully, when I run application.